# How to install nvidia docker in alienware windows 10 system?

Tags: windows, tensorflow, web-deployment, nvidia-docker

I am trying to use the tensorflow-GPU serving in the windows 10 system. But I haven't found any solution for installing the Nvidia docker for windows. Please give me a suggestion, how to use the Windows machine GPU in deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of `nvidia-docker` and `nvidia-container-runtime` have support for Windows, and there are no plans so far to support the OS either. Only linux host is supported.

Check the [FAQ here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#platform-support):

> ### Is macOS supported?
>
> No, we do not support macOS (regardless of the version), however you
>   can use the native macOS Docker client to deploy your containers
>   remotely (refer to the [dockerd documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#description)).
>
> ### Is Microsoft Windows supported?
>
> No, we do not support Microsoft Windows (regardless of the version),
>   however you can use the native Microsoft Windows Docker client to
>   deploy your containers remotely (refer to the [dockerd
>   documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#description)).